# count the number of words in a string separated by spaces and/or punctuation marks

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help please .
I want to create a program that can count the number of words in a string separated by spaces and/or punctuation marks. You should only count words where the vowels and consonants are alternating. A word can not have two consecutive vowels or consonants. Single letter words are not counted. Ignore anything in the file that is not a vowel or a constant. Replace anything that is not in the alphabet with a single space. Case sensitivity of each letter does not matter.

Alphabet to use
Vowels -- A E I O U Y
Consonants -- B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Z

Input:
A string eg "Hello there great new world"

Output:
Number of desired words found in the input string above. eg 1

Sample:

"Welcome to Radix!!!" == 2 (to Radix)

"Everybody, thanks you for trying this out." == 2 (everybody for)

"Hello there great new world" == 1 (new)

"Mary,had,a,little,lamb" == 2 (Mary had)

Comment: I edited the expected results, "you" is not alternating.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string,re

VOWELS=[x.lower() for x in "A E I O U Y".split(" ")]
CONSONANTS = [x.lower() for x in "B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Z".split(" ") ]
FILE_PATH = 'sentences.txt'
PUNCT = '[ %s]'% string.punctuation #[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]


def isAlt(word):
    #True if word is valid
    word=word.lower() #Non-case-sensitive
    for x in range(len(word)-1):
        if not (word[x] in VOWELS and word[x+1] in CONSONANTS)and not(word[x+1] in VOWELS and word[x] in CONSONANTS):
            #Sorry about that condition, I can probably return that whole line
            return False
    return True



for line in open(FILE_PATH,'r'):
    out=re.split(PUNCT,line.strip())
    out=[x for x in out if x and len(x)>1 and isAlt(x)]
    print(len(out))
```

This scans the file and for each line finds the valid words and prints out the number of words that match your conditions. You can change `len(out)` to `out` for the list instead of the number.

Comment: Thanks T Bell but iam having trouble trying to understand

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain what you are having difficulty understanding. That way I will be able to change my answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: T Bell.... Thats a great answer and it works.....Could you please elaborate the following lines of code.......PUNCT = '[ %s]'% string.punctuation .......... if not (word[x] in VOWELS and word[x+1] in CONSONANTS)and not(word[x+1] in VOWELS and word[x] in CONSONANTS) .....................out=[x for x in out if x and len(x)>1 and isAlt(x)].............Thanks

Comment: The first line is making a regular expression (from the re module) with all the punctuation in it to split the string. The %s means replace with a string, so the % sign outside the quotation marks replaces the %s  with string.punctuation (I have commented what the string is after it).

The second line checks each letter to see if the current one is a consonant, the next one is a vowel and vice-versa. 

The third lines uses the list of words and filters out the words that don't meet the conditions.

I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: YES Thanks ,...I highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

This is a homework, isn't it?

Try this regular expression:

```
\b[aeiouy]?([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy])*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]?\b
```

It will find all words with alternating vowels/consonants. Beware, it will pass single-letter words as well, filter them out subsequently. And run it with ignore-case flag.